# Ubuntu bash script grepping and cutting on first column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cut

I am trying to implement a bash script that will take the piped input and cut the first column and return a total. The difference is that the cut is not from a file, but from the piped input. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
total=$(cut -f1 $1 | numsum)
echo $total
```

Basically, in my scenario the first column will always be from the passed input.

Example usuage is:

```
 ./script.sh "cat data.txt | grep -i status | grep something"
```

data.txt contains:

```
1 status
2 something
```

This will produce something like:

2

How can this be achieved? I have noticed the cut only works for files only. I cannot see any examples on Google.

Comment: Why not just `cat data.txt | grep something | ./script.sh`?

Comment: This is the preferred option by my company. So this is the limitation. The example shown above is pretty simple, but this will be used for something much bigger.

Comment: Why not just do awk '/something/ { print $2 }' data.txt?

Comment: If I do total=$(awk '{printf $1}' | numsum) echo $total that does not work. It  hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue myself. The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
total=$(eval $1 | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}')
echo $total
```